# Flutter | Error: Couldn't resolve the package

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

I created a package that is a collection of my own helper classes for faster developing...

The package also included firebase_analytics: which requires a native implementation for each platform i want it to run. Even if i dont wanted to use firebase at all, but still wanted to use my package i was forced to create firebase-config files for the app, because the app crashes if the firebase_analytics package does not find a valid file for the specific platform. To avoid those things i splitted my package in two packages.

1. The Core-Package: All helper classes that run native dart code
2. Optional extension: Only the classes that need the firebase implementation

So if i want to use the package without firebase i just have to depend on the core.
If i want to use the firebase variant i could simply depend the firebase package, because the extension package itself depends on the core-package in its own pubspec.yaml file.

PROBLEM: Since i restructured my package like i described, all my apps that depend on it are not building anymore. The console says that all packages that i depend on in my two packages can not be found. This error occures both ways: With firebase & without.

ERROR: (Scroll down for the complete console output)
[image: Console-Error]

MY ATTEMPTS:

- "flutter clean" & "flutter pub get" in every package and app folder
- "flutter pub cache repair"

CORE-PACKAGE Pubspec.yaml:
[image: essentials_core]

FIREBASE-Extension Pubspec.yaml:
[image: essentials_firebase]

Plain Console Output:
pastebin.com/m14cbqDV

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue while i was making a build in Xcode 13.So I had upgraded my flutter version 2.8.0 to 2.10.2 and also removed the version of all firebase dependencies, then the issue was finally solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issues and resolved them by removing package versions. Issues like this often arise due to mismatched versions of packages (eg firebase_core, firebase analytics). Please try to remove versions of the firebase packages or the whole packages. (like firebase_analytics :).

Comment: Are you sure thats the problem? I know what kind of error you mean, but that does not look like this at all... In fact i did not changed any version numbers during my restructuring and it worked like a charm before...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad! As you can see i moved my dependencys to the dev section of my pubspec.yaml. They should be placed in the dependency section.